# Pandas: How to set index to a column value, group columns, and return values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a df as follows:

```
         State  Country   Pop       GDP
   1     MD     USA        433100   1222
   2     TX     USA        99934123 324234
   3     B.C.   MEX        324599   5343
   4     OAX    MEX        43322    986
   5     BC     CAN        3431     643
   6     NS     CAN        8749     3535
```

I want to group by Country and find the max GDP and min GDP, returning that as well as new column names so that it looks something like this:

```
      PoorState   GDP    Pop       RichState   GDP      Pop
USA   MD          1222   433100    TX          324234   99934123
MEX   OAX         986    43322     B.C.        5343     324599
...
```

I've tried this to get the min and max for each state:

```
df.groupby('state').agg({'GDP':min, 'GDP':max})[['GDP','GDP']].reset_index()
```

but just the min works while the max doesn't.

```
  State   GDP    GDP
  MD      1222   1222
  OAX     986    986
```

--
I know that I can do this to set the index:
`newdf = df.set_index('region')`

I think I'm trying to figure out if I can do this all on one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do `groupby` with `rank` create the category then `pivot`

```
df['new'] =  df.groupby('Country')['GDP'].rank().map({1:'Poor',2:'Rich'})
out = df.pivot(index='Country',columns = 'new').sort_index(level=1,axis=1)
out.columns = out.columns.map('_'.join)
out.reset_index(inplace=True)
out
Out[348]: 
  Country  GDP_Poor  Pop_Poor State_Poor  GDP_Rich  Pop_Rich State_Rich
0     CAN       643      3431         BC      3535      8749         NS
1     MEX       986     43322        OAX      5343    324599       B.C.
2     USA      1222    433100         MD    324234  99934123         TX
```